# Unable to create AWS Elasticsearch, it's required fine-grained access control

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create AWS elastic search I have selected Public access and I don't want to check "Enable fine-grained access control", while I'm trying to enter JSON defined access policy I get an error and can't continue. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NICOX.png)
the section "Enable fine-grained access control" is disabled

Comment: Did you supply an access policy? Is it restrictive?

Comment: Please share your access policy

Comment: yes I tried, very simple one
`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "######"
    }
  ]`
} which is valid but the point is that AWS is asking me to "Enable fine-grained access control" as you can see in the image, it's already disabled for me I can't have it